# Dividing a number by zero

Tags: arithmetic, natural-numbers

Why can't you divide a number by zero?
It is possible to say $\sqrt{-1}$ is an imaginary number $i$, but why can't you say $\frac{1}{0}$ is also an imaginary number $z$ (for example)?

Comment: You seem to be under the impression that an 'imaginary number' is a convenience for a seemingly-impossible mathematical operation.  The number $i$ satisfying $i^2=-1$ is supremely important. Indeed, the term 'imaginary' is unconstructive and unenlightening; 'complex' number speaks more to its utility.

Comment: You can, but it would be useless. (Also, you'd have to use some other name since "imaginary number" is already taken.) [MJD wrote a great answer investigating what would happen if you did, here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/why-not-to-extend-the-set-of-natural-numbers-to-make-it-closed-under-division-by).

Comment: Also, the IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754), which is what most computers use, *does* define division by 0: it says that the result of dividing any number by 0 is the special number "NaN" (which stands for "Not a Number"). The [discussion by MJD](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/125208/205) essentially tells you what happens.

Comment: @Frank, I at least consider "complex" to be as undeserved a name as "imaginary", but I suppose we're stuck with centuries of tradition at this point... if only we had better names for something so useful!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Suppose $x=\frac{1}{0}$. Then we should have $x\cdot0=1$, this is not possible since $0$ times any number will give $0$.

In contrast, the idea to let $\sqrt{-1}=i$ is extending the number system which could satisfy all the calculation rules by itself.

---

Maybe it will be easier to understand this by taking an example: Let $x=\frac{1}{0}$. Then $$1=x\cdot0=x(1-1)=x\cdot1-x\cdot1=x-x=0$$LHS$\neq$RHS, a contradiction.

Comment: @exploringnet, no number would satisfy this since $0$ times any number should be $0$ by considering the operation rules of field.

Comment: if you were ever to label $1/0$ as a quantity, I think you would be forced to formally define it to br $\infty$.  For instance, evaluating a function $f$ on the Riemann Sphere at $\infty$ amounts to evaluating $f(1/z)$ at $z=0$.  There are plenty of other instances where we "invert zero", but you must use a great deal of care when doing this.

Comment: In addition to John Martin's comment, even you define it to be $\infty$, there are numerous different directions of $\infty$, in which case we treat them as infinity points in affine geometry. But surely this is off topic.

Comment: More carefully, the point is that *when you add $i$ to the number system (field), it plays nicely with all the rules*, but *if you add $1/0$ to the system, you have to remove some rules, or make special exceptions to them*.

Comment: @exploringnet To put Easy's comment another way, if you define $Z\cdot 0=1$, then you're not just putting conditions on $Z$, you're changing the definition of $0$.

Answer (score 5):

Another way to see the problem is by looking at limits:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x->0^+} \frac{1}{x} = \infty$$
But:
$$\displaystyle \lim_{x->0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty$$

And since there's no preference to any one-sided limit, the limit should not exist and there isn't a specific value to the function $\frac1x$ at 0.