# Could we "invent" a number $h$ such that $h = {{1}\over{0}}$, similarly to the way we "invented" $i=\sqrt{-1}$?

Tags: soft-question, arithmetic, number-systems

$\sqrt{-1}$ was completely undefined in the world before complex numbers. So we came up with $i$.

$1\over0$ is completely undefined in today's world; is there a reason we haven't come up with a new unit to define it? Is it even possible, or would it create logical inconsistencies?
 What would be the effect on modern math if we did so?

Comment: In the context of [Wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory), division is always defined, even division by zero.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/why-not-to-extend-the-set-of-natural-numbers-to-make-it-closed-under-division-by

Answer (score 7):

You could do this, but you'd have to sacrifice associativity of multiplication. Presumably $h\cdot 0$ should equal $1$, but then $h\cdot(0\cdot 0) = h\cdot 0 = 1$, while $(h\cdot 0)\cdot 0 = 1\cdot 0 =0 $

Comment: +1. I might add that another problem is that you need a different $h_x$ for every nonzero numerator $x$, and then the situation gets even worse in the case $x=0$.

Comment: I think you can do it if you also introduce an indeterminate $k$, and define equality appropriately.

Comment: @Ian That's true, but we could define $h_x = x\cdot h$ without much (further) issue.

Comment: @Zach: I don't think so - you've fallen into the associativity trap!

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't think I have. $0\cdot (x\cdot h) := x$. We couldn't move the parentheses, but we already knew that.

Answer (score 0):

The imaginary unit was "invented" because we wanted to solve algebraic equations with formulas involving roots.
There seems to be no reason for "inventing" such a number.
This is the main reason (I think) why we don't invent such a number.
Whould it be usefull anywhere at all?

Comment: Actually, we do. This has been invented long ago, in different algebraic structures.

Answer (score 0):

There are the dual numbers, which is another two dimensional associative algebra over the reals like the complex numbers. The basis elements are 1 and h, where we define h as a nonzero number whose square is zero.

Comment: That doesn't seem to have anything in particular to do with _division_ by zero.

Comment: No, not directly, but seeing as he thought up this idea as an analogue to the complex numbers I thought he might be interested in an analogue to the complex numbers that's actually interesting algebraically.

Comment: You still cannot divide by it. By the way, division is usually prohibited not only by zero but by any zero divisors.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't mathematically consistent with our concepts of multiplication. However, in a similar vein of reasoning, mathematicians sometimes employ the extended real numbers, which are basically the real numbers with two new elements, positive and negative infinity. Although it still isn't 1/0, defining these two numbers has a lot of use in measure theory.

Comment: There is also projective real line with just one added element, which is closer to division by zero.