# Why is division by $0$ not defined in division theorem?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

In the general division theorem, there is a condition that when considering $\frac{a}{b}$, we require $b\ne 0$. My question is, why is $0$ left out? In school we were taught that anything divided by $0$ was infinity so we carried out the calculations by taking eg. $\frac{10}{0}=\infty$. Thanks for the insights!

Comment: You were lied to in school.

Comment: sorry that is not the answer i am looking for.

Comment: But that's the correct answer. You must be looking for an incorrect answer. What would you like it to say?

Comment: "In school we were taught that anything divided by 0 was infinity so we carried out the calculations by taking eg. $\frac {10}0=∞$"  But you can't *do* anything with that.  And it doesn't work.  $2 = \frac {10}{5} = \frac {10}0\cdot \frac 0{5} =\frac {10}0\cdot \frac {1}{\frac 50} = \infty \cdot \frac 1 {\infty} = \frac {10}0\cdot \frac 1{\frac {10}0} = \frac {10}0\cdot \frac 0{10} =\frac {10}{10} = 1$.... It's pointless.  Utterly pointless.

Comment: @fleablood it's not that it's pointless, it's wrong.

Comment: "it's not that it's pointless, it's wrong."  Well.... that depends on what is *right*.  We *can* define anything anyway we want.  All that matters is its consistent.  So we *could* make up some things we call numbers and some operation we call division and some rule that any number divided by $0$ is the number we call $\infty$ and that wouldn't be "wrong" .... but it wouldn't be the arithmetic we know and love and the arithmetic it *would* be would be .... utterly pointless.

Comment: And yes, if he *was* taught that anything divided by $0$ was infinity, then he *was* lied to.  .... Now that I think about it I was taught many inconsistent thing is school and I think I was taught that.  But I was also taught it was wrong as well.  And I was even taught that we couldn't divide by $0$ *because* it would be infinity. .... they meant well but teachers don't always know what they are talking about.  It is not true (and in fact it is fairly meaningless) to say "$\frac {10}0 = \infty$".  It's just not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us suppose that we could define division like that. Let $a$ and $b$ be two numbers and say that
$$ \frac{a}{0}=\infty\quad\textrm{and}\quad\frac{b}{0}=\infty. $$
Therefore, we have that
$$ a=0\cdot\infty=b.$$
That is, $a=b$ for any two numbers $a$, $b$. There are many contradictions like this you can come up with. But lets think about it differently. What is division? The expression $a\div b$ is saying "what number times $b$ is equal to $a$?". So, what number times $0$ is equal to $10$?

Comment: is it the fact that we do not know what number times 0 is equal to 10 that it is left undefined?

Comment: It's not that we don't know, it's that one doesn't exist.

Comment: how do you prove it doesn't exist? is there a proof?

Comment: $x\cdot 0 =0$ for all $x$

Comment: what is the proof of x.0 = 0 for all x?

Comment: It depends what axiomatic theory you begin with. There will always either be a proof that $x\cdot 0=0$ or it will itself be an axiom. The latter is the case for Peano's axioms, the former for set theoretic models.

Comment: thanks for help!

Comment: Let $0\cdot x = K$ Then $K = 0\cdot x = (0 + 0)\cdot x = 0\cdot x + 0\cdot x = K + K$.  So $0 = K-K = K + K - K = K + 0 = K$.  So $K=0$.  So $0\cdot x = K = 0$.  That's the proof.

Comment: Infra-ten. It's a secret to everybody.

Comment: @tomasliam The answers at [Why not to extend the set of natural numbers to make it closed under division by zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/125186/25554) discuss in detail what kinds of things go wrong if we try to allow division by zero.  It can be made to work, but not in any useful way.

Comment: @MJD You can define anything you like. My point is it won't match with the usual properties of division and multiplication, and if you expect it to do so, many contradictions will arise.

Comment: Yes, we are in agreement. As you say, many contradictions will arise; the answers I linked to give details.

Answer (score 1):

Say you define $a / 0 = x$, so $a = x \cdot 0$, i.e., $a = 0$, *regardless of what $x$ may be*. No other $a$ can be "divided" by 0, and the "result" of that "division" is anything whatsoever. The idea of "inverse of 0" just can't be twisted into making sense without throwing out much of the rest of the properties of the operations on numbers.