# Why can't division by zero be defined just like iota?

Tags: complex-analysis, elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, definition

If we could define i=$\sqrt{-1}$, then why can't we say k= $\frac{1}{0}$ ?

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259584/why-dont-we-define-imaginary-numbers-for-every-impossibility and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/125186/why-not-to-extend-the-set-of-natural-numbers-to-make-it-closed-under-division-by.