# Does the definition of division by zero in Wheel theory actually make sense?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

I came across this question : [Will Division by Zero be Defined Eventually?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/144715/will-division-by-zero-be-defined-eventually)

and was very surprised that there is a theory, called [Wheel theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory), which tries to make the division by zero meaningful.

> Must this theory be taken serious ?

Googling Wheel theory was not very enlightening. If I understand right , $\frac{1}{0}$ is considered to be an additional element, like the point of infinity. But I cannot see how the theory deals with the usual issues occuring. In particular, multiplying the additional element with $0$ could be any number because $\frac{1}{0}$ and $\frac{2}{0}$ , for example lead to the same element, right ?

Can anyone shed some light on this strange theory ?

Comment: You could give a reference...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Basically, I only found this article : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory

Comment: I guess you should start from the two papers cited on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheel_theory): [this](http://www.cs.swan.ac.uk/~csetzer/articles/wheel.pdf) and [this](https://www2.math.su.se/reports/2001/11/).

Comment: It all looks rather futile to me: multiplying $1/0=2/0$ by $0$ will lead to $0/0=0/0$ and $0/0$ is the new "number" that's used as a dump for meaningless expressions...

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I don't see any meaningful definition either. But in the article in Wikipedia, no doubts or critic is mentioned. So, you also disagree with the "perfectly well-defined division by zero", as mentioned in the linked question, right ?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco It is very unlikely that I will study those papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate questions here: whether wheels are *meaningful* and whether they are *significant/useful*. The answer to the first question is clearly **yes**: the definition, regardless of whether it matches intuitions, makes perfect sense and gives a well-defined class of algebraic structures. So a certain amount of the negative tone of the question, in my opinion, is not justified.

But that's not the big question: more importantly, should we care - or better, what reasons are there for one to care? At a glance I can't find any real applications of the notion. That said, there could be subtle ones: for example, while the generalization from unital to non-unital rings may appear uninteresting, it in fact has some important consequences (in many ways the collection of non-unital rings is better behaved than the collection of unital rings). So I would tentatively say: **based on my current knowledge, the best reason for you to care about wheel theory is the extent to which wheels are interesting in their own right to you**. For me personally (at least, at the moment) this means that I"m not interested in wheel theory - although of course that could change, either by virtue of learning about some cool applications or by virtue of having a "oh wait that *is* cool!" moment.